# Understanding import syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, node-modules

Importing functions from another file in javascript

```
import { myFunction1, myFunction2 } from './myFileName';
```

Hi, I'm confused by the dictionary `{ }` like syntax here.

Questions are:

1. is `{ myFunction1, myFunction2 }` a dictionary/map?

I then experimented with the syntax, I tried to create a dictionary/map with functions in them.
It turns out that it works. It seems like a function variable name is turned into a key and the function is the value.

```
let funcDic = {
    foo, bar
}
function foo() { console.log('foo') } 
function bar() { console.log('bar')}
funcDic['foo']() // prints foo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is [ES6 object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
const record = { user: { name: 'Joe Bloggs' } }

const { user } = record

// user is { name: 'Joe Bloggs' }

const { name } = user

// name is 'Joe Bloggs'

// shorthand for:

const user = record.user
const name = user.name
```